# How to create a project in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I am new to TexStudio. I want to create a new project so I can compose all the projects files inside a single directory or folders. When I open the `File` menu, it create a new file and there is no option to create a new directory. 
I also looked at the tool bar and all the icons. I can not see anything that allow me create a new project (directory or folder). Can you help me please? this is important to me. There is no way I can make the projecs files mixed in one place.

Comment: Projects are implicit in TeXstudio's philosophy. See [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#%D9%90does-texstudio-support-projects-ie-mulli-file-documents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TeXstudio team has already covered this in their [FAQ](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#%D9%90does-texstudio-support-projects-ie-multi-file-documents).

The short answer is that the option to explicitly "create a project" is not available (not necessary) because projects are implicit in their philosophy: TeXstudio automatically infers the relations between your project files, and if that fails, there are alternatives like using "Magic commands" to specify project root files etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Explicitly declaring a document as root of a project

### (when automatic fails)

As @Troy said, the project is automatically created by *TexStudio*, when in a `.tex` file, e.g. `front-page.tex`, you include another `.tex` files, e.g., `\input{./chapters/motivation.tex}`.
Now, if you open in *TexStudio* the file `motivation.tex`, it should be automatically recognised as part of the project `front-page.tex`.

I had, however, many files included in my "main" file `front-page.tex` and some of them were not recognised as part of the project. My solution was to **explicitly** declare my "main" file as **root file**:

1. Go to the *side panel* and select *structure*. If your desired root document is open should be listed there.
2. Select your desired root document and open the *context menu* and click on `Set as explicit root document`.

[image]

In that way, *TexStudio* is forced to take the chosen document (in my case `front-page.tex`) as root of a project. And it will be always compiled as root no matter in which file you are editing in *TexStudio*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a project in TeXstudio for some reason, you can do with a hack. Add the following to your "main" project file:

```
% !TeX TXS-SCRIPT = openproj
% //Trigger = ?load-this-file
% files = [
%   "./file1.tex",
%   "./file2.tex",
% ]
% for (i in files) {
%   files[i] = app.getAbsoluteFilePath(files[i]);
% }
% for (i in files) {
%   app.load(app.getAbsoluteFilePath(files[i]));
% }
% TXS-SCRIPT-END
```

This script opens the specified files, as soon as the main file is opened. It is pretty much self-explanatory javascript code. To explain the non-obvious parts:

- The `//Trigger` statement activates the script (when it is loaded).
- The separation in two for loops is needed in case the project files are in separate directories.
  If you merge the loops and give `files = ["./foo/bar.tex", "./baz.tex"]`, it will try to load `./foo/bar.tex` and `./foo/baz.tex`

In case you are looking for further info for the scripting, have a look at [their docs](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)

This should not be necessary, if TeXstudio correctly recognizes your project. I'd advise against this script if it is not necessary, you'll save yourself some headache.